# How to sort data in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have `Items` data which I am attempting to display array values sorted by `cost` field in `costtable` array when `roomname` is `Double` and `type` is `2`.Here is my code:

**Json:**

```
    {
        "index": 1,
        "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1023632_1004876",
        "costtable": [
            {
                "roomname": "Single",
                "room_id": "1023632_479490,1004876_385485",
                "family": [
                    {
                        "title": "adult 1",
                        "cost": 3.7568000,
                        "unit": "10",
                        "type": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1088496_1005362",
        "costtable": [
            {
                "roomname": "Double",
                "room_id": "1088496_447339,1005362_415279",
                "family": [
                    {
                        "title": "adult 1",
                        "cost": 5.6868000,
                        "unit": "10",
                        "type": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 3,
        "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1141859_1005529",
        "costtable": [
            {
                "roomname": "Single",
                "room_id": "1141859_74888,1005529_870689",
                "family": [
                    {
                        "title": "adult 1",
                        "cost": 5.9586000,
                        "unit": "10",
                        "type": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Items: [],
            library: null,
            perPage: 20,
            currentPage: 1,
            maxPage: null,

        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/json', {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
                let CostSort = Maindata.map(a => {
                    return this.renderSort(a)
                })
                Maindata.sort((a, b) => a.CostSort - b.CostSort);
                this.setState(state => ({
                    ...state,
                    Items: Maindata
                }), () => {
                    this.reorganiseLibrary()
                })
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))

    }
    reorganiseLibrary = () => {
        const { perPage, Items } = this.state;
        let library = Items;
        library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
        this.setState({
            library,
            currentPage: 1,
            maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
        });
    };

    renderSort(element) {
        let indents = []
        let lenFamilies = element.costtable.length
        for (let i = 0; i < lenFamilies; i++) {
            if (element.costtable[i].roomname.indexOf('Double') > -1) {
                for (let j = 0; j < element.costtable[i].family.length; j++) {
                    if (element.costtable[i].family[j].type == 2) {
                        indents.push(element.costtable[i].family[j].cost)
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return (indents)

    }

    // Previous Page
    previousPage = event => {
        this.setState({
            currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
        });
    };
    // Next Page 
    nextPage = event => {
        this.setState({
            currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
        });
    };



    // handle per page
    handlePerPage = (evt) =>
        this.setState({
            perPage: evt.target.value
        }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

    // handle render of library
    renderLibrary = () => {
        const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
        if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
            return '';
        }
        return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
            <div className="item-list">
                {item.index}
            </div>
        ));
    };
    render() {
        const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="wrapper-data">
                    {this.renderLibrary()}
                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <ul id="page-numbers">
                    <li className="nexprevPage">
                        {currentPage !== 1 && (
                            <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                        )}
                    </li>
                    <li className="controlsPage active">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                    <li className="restControls">...</li>
                    <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                    <li className="nexprevPage">
                        {(currentPage < maxPage) && (<button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                        )}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Content'));
```

This code does not give me any errors but displays the values in an unsorted format. How can I sort it?

**New Code**

```
  Maindata.sort((a, b) => {
            let lenFamilies = a.costtable.length
            for (let i = 0; i < lenFamilies; i++) {
                if( a.costtable[i].roomname.indexOf('Double') > -1){
                    for (let j = 0; j < a.costtable[i].family.length; j++) {
                        if( a.costtable[i].family[j].type == 2){

                        a.costtable[i].family[j].cost- b.costtable[i].family[j].cost
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the exact formula that you are using to sort, but what you are doing before the sort is wrong.

In your `componentDidMount`

```
let CostSort = Maindata.map(a => { return this.renderSort(a) })
```

This returns an array into a variable called `CostSort` and does not affect `MainData` in any way.

However, later on you do this.

```
Maindata.sort((a, b) => a.CostSort - b.CostSort);
```

For first iteration, this will compare Maindata[0] and Maindata[1]. Note that there is no CostSort in either of the objects and hence you are performing operation of `undefined - undefined` which is `NaN`. Therefore no sorting happens.

I would suggest you use only the `sort` function and do your comparison between two values there.

```
Maindata.sort((a, b) => {
 // Do your calculation here

 if(a should be before b) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

P.S The convention for variable in js is `camelCase` and not `PascalCase`. So, `Maindata` should he `mainData`.

EDIT:
Here is a simple sort implementation which works for the above case, you can expand on it according to your full use case.

```
Maindata.sort((a, b) => {
  let lenFamilies = a.costtable.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < lenFamilies; i++) {
    if (
      a.costtable[i].roomname.includes("Double") &&
      !b.costtable[i].roomname.includes("Double")
    ) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (
      !a.costtable[i].roomname.includes("Double") &&
      b.costtable[i].roomname.includes("Double")
    ) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.costtable[i].roomname.indexOf("Double") > -1) {
      for (let j = 0; j < a.costtable[i].family.length; j++) {
        if (a.costtable[i].family[j].type == 2) {
          a.costtable[i].family[j].cost - b.costtable[i].family[j].cost;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Hassaan Tauqir for your answer, but how can I access to `costtable`array in `Maindata.sort((a, b) => {})` and do  my  calculation ?

Comment: I did what you said in **New Code** part but displays the values in an unsorted format yet!

Comment: @Maya a and b are objects from your array of Maindata, therefore, you can access costtable using a.costtable and b.costtable. Try using console.log(a, b) in the sort and you will see the object in your browser console

Comment: @Hassaan Tauqir Yes I can see the object in my browser console and if you take look at **New Code** part of my code I can see `a.costtable[i].family[j].cost` also in my browser console but  values are not in an unsorted format

Comment: Can you give me detailed info as to how you want to sort your array, so I can make up a solution. I am not aware of your exact sorting logic.

Comment: For making more understandable, based on `Json` below, the values should be  displayed in a below sorted format  : 
 ```
<div className="item-list">2</div>
<div className="item-list">1</div>
<div className="item-list">3</div>
```

Comment: The `roomname` field of  Object by `Index=2` is `Double` so it must be the first item shown in output . I want the objects be sorted based on Cost of Objects which has 'Double' roomname

Comment: I see, you were only comparing the costs here, and not taking into consideration if both indexes were "Double" rooms or not. I have added an implementation which works for the above use case in the answer, you can expand on it further according to your need.

Comment: Thanks @Hassaan Tauqir for your answer, I did what you said an I can see both `a.costtable[i].family[j].cost`and `b.costtable[i].family[j].cos ` in my browser console but display array values  in an unsorted format again!

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the algorithms (bubble, quicksort, by inserting ...). There is possible of sorting in UI context.

Your json have:
**title | cost | unit | type**

What type of sort You need? (title is **string** (can eg. sort alphabetically), then cost, unit & type are **number** (ascending + descending)

It's will be helpfull - when in future You provide only neccessary piece of code.

---

Here it's ellegant minimalistic function responsible for **asc/desc** sorting.

Firstly it's need to pass the **props**(which You wan't to sort) to **values** state.

```
function App() {
  const [ascValue, setAscValue] = useState(true);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([10, 5, 12, 1, 2, 900, 602]);

  function sortValues() {
    const compare = ascValue ? (a, b) => a - b : (a, b) => b - a;
    setValues([...values].sort(compare));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    sortValues();
  }, [ascValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{ascValue.toString()}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => setAscValue(!ascValue)}>Toggle Asc</button>
      {values.map(v => (
        <p key={v}>{v}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Here is sorting by cost for your object:

```
let text = [{
    "index": 1,
    "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1023632_1004876",
    "costtable": [
        {
            "roomname": "Single",
            "room_id": "1023632_479490,1004876_385485",
            "family": [
                {
                    "title": "adult 1",
                    "cost": 3.7568000,
                    "unit": "10",
                    "type": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "index": 2,
    "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1088496_1005362",
    "costtable": [
        {
            "roomname": "Double",
            "room_id": "1088496_447339,1005362_415279",
            "family": [
                {
                    "title": "adult 1",
                    "cost": 5.6868000,
                    "unit": "10",
                    "type": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "index": 3,
    "id": "5e3961face022d16a03b1de9_1141859_1005529",
    "costtable": [
        {
            "roomname": "Single",
            "room_id": "1141859_74888,1005529_870689",
            "family": [
                {
                    "title": "adult 1",
                    "cost": 5.9586000,
                    "unit": "10",
                    "type": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]

const App = () =>{

    const usersWithName = Object.keys(text).map(function(key) {
        var user = text[key];
        return user.costtable[0].family[0].cost;
      });

    let costArray = usersWithName

    const [ascValue, setAscValue] = useState(true);
    const [values, setValues] = useState(costArray);


        function sortValues() {
            const compare = ascValue ? (a, b) => a - b : (a, b) => b - a;
            setValues([...values].sort(compare));
          }


        useEffect(() => {
            sortValues();
          }, [ascValue]);




        return (
        <div>
            <h3>{ascValue.toString()}</h3>
            <button onClick={() => setAscValue(!ascValue)}>Toggle Asc</button>
            {values.map(v => (
                <p key={v}>{v}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
        );
    }

export default App;
```

---

I don't have idea of **performance** in this case + if in your json are more costtable & family it should iterate by [i] iterator.